# Adding selected number of divs inside another div

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to create an app that will roll number of dice decided by the user.
I want every dice to be in a separate div but I struggle to implement a code inserting divs into HTML.

As a test I created a button that would insert a single div into another div, here is what I got so far:

```
<div id="diceTable">
    <button onclick="addDice()">Add Dice</button>
</div>
```

JS being:

```
function addDice(){
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = "<p> here will be a dice</p>";

div.getElementById('dice').appendChild(div);
}
```

But it doesnt seem to work. Maybe im using wrong methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small typo - use `document.getElementById('dice').appendChild(div)` instead of `div.getElementById('dice').appendChild(div)`.

```js
function addDice() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = "<p> here will be a dice</p>";
  document.getElementById('dice').appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="diceTable">
  <button onclick="addDice()">Add Dice</button>
</div>
<div id='dice'></div>
```

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe I was looking at it for good 5 minutes and didnt see this emberassment... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is straight out of W3C school https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_div.asp

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("DIV");
    var t = document.createTextNode("This is a div element.");
    x.setAttribute("style", "background-color: pink;");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

Use append.child rather than innerHTML

Comment: Note that `createTextNode()` doesn't accept HTML code.  There should be nothing wrong with using `innerHTML` directly.

Comment: Not certain, but it's possible the object doesn't exist yet. I've had problems like that before. Using the append circumvents any DOM establishment issues which may or may not be there. If his original code isn't working it's likely because the object doesn't exist yet.

Comment: For a beginner like me innerHTML seems like an easier concept to grasp for now and it appears to be working after I fixed embarassing typo.

Comment: I see. For future reference a problem I have often encountered is attempting to contact objects before they are rendered. These sorts of problems can often be intermittent since sometimes a program runs quicker than at others. I thought this might be the problem you were having thus my proposed solution. :-) Glad you were able to resolve your issue.